# Accessing indices of Swift arrays safely: Ext return not an optional?

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type, indices

In the docs, there's an example of an extension to add safe and unknowing access to any index (real or imagined) of a Swift array *(Edit - SO Docs is now defunct so this example was inserted at the bottom of this question)*.

Swift arrays normally crash if the index doesn't exist. It seems this extension is explicitly designed to solve this problem by returning `nil` if there's nothing at the index requested.

The extension looks like this:

```
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Use of the extension looks like this:

```
if let thirdValue = array[safe: 2] {
    print(thirdValue)
}
```

Trying this out in playgrounds reveals nothing coming back for an unsafe index. That I can tell. Not an optional, not a nil, nothing. And no crash.

How is this not an optional that's coming back from this when it's a safe or unsafe index value? I admire that this works, just don't really understand how it works, or what it's doing.

### UPDATE

As [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) helpfully points out, most of my problem is not understanding/remembering/knowing that `if let` is doing a forceful unwrapping of the optional that results from the extension's function returning a value that is most definitely an *Optional*. If this forceful unwrapping fails to divulge a value (ie no value at the index returns an optional containing `nil`) this prevents the `{trailing closure}` from being invoked.

However it brings up another subquestion.

If using a variable to capture the return value, like so:

```
let val = array[safe: 2]
print("val:",  val)
```

regardless of the result, it is an optional, but Swift provides a "helpful" error saying:

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to Any

I apologise if this should be a new question: Why is this being coerced to `Any`? Why can't (and why doesn't it) simply remain as an Optional of type `Int?`

---

> The following content is from "Accessing indices safely" from Stack Overflow Documentation
>   ([archived here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170816193820/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/284/arrays/)); copyright 2017 by [Moriya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891013/moriya); licensed
>   under CC BY-SA 3.0. An archive of the full Stack Overflow
>   Documentation content can be found at archive.org, in which this
>   example is indexed by its topic ID: 284, as example: 16567.

By adding the following extension to array indices can be accessed without knowing if the index is inside bounds.

```
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

example:

```
if let thirdValue = array[safe: 2] {
    print(thirdValue)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if let val = someOptional { ... }
```

is an *optional binding.* If `someOptional != nil` then the condition
is true and the *unwrapped* value `someOptional!` is assigned to `val`.
If `someOptional == nil` then the condition is false.

So in your case

```
if let thirdValue = array[safe: 2] {
    print(thirdValue)
}
```

the condition is true (and the if-block executed) if `array[safe: 2] != nil`. In that case, the unwrapped value is assigned to `thirdValue`.
On the other hand, if `array[safe: 2]` returns `nil` then the condition
is false and the if-block is not executed.

You can print the return value without using an if-condition to verify
that it is `nil`:

```
let array = [1, 2]
let val = array[safe: 2]
print("val:",  val) // "val: nil"
```

With Swift 3.0.1 (Xcode 8.1, tested with GM seed) this will cause compiler warnings

```
main.swift:12:16: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to Any
print("val:",  val)
               ^~~
main.swift:12:16: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
print("val:",  val)
               ^~~
                   ?? 
main.swift:12:16: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
print("val:",  val)
               ^~~
                  !
main.swift:12:16: note: explicitly cast to Any with 'as Any' to silence this warning
print("val:",  val)
               ^~~
                   as Any
```

as a consequence of the implementation of
[SE-0140 Warn when Optional converts to Any, and bridge Optional As Its Payload Or NSNull](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md).

The warning can be suppressed with

```
print("val:",  val as Any) // "val: nil"
```

Comment: argh, "if let" catches me out, AGAIN!!! I'd be a gazillionaire if I had a penny for everytime this seemingly innocuous little trap/trick catches me out unawares.

Comment: I'm getting (in playgrounds) non-optional values reported as the results, though. Is this just to mess with my head? To clarify, the result seems to be either a distinct (not-optional) value, or nil. Not an optional returning from this, ever. Perhaps I'm failing to understand your answer. It seems to me that you're saying an optional is returned, but you start with If... so I'm not sure.

Comment: Shit. I'm still not grokking "if let". it's a forced conversion to non-optional, right?

Comment: I have rewritten the answer – is that more clear? The warning "Expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to Any" was introduced with Swift 3.1, see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md.

Comment: Just when I thought optionals couldn't get anymore convoluted... FARK!!!

Comment: After reading your link to the evolution of this... Does this mean `print()`, as implemented by Apple, is done in Objective-C? I don't see how this `as Any` nonsense should be coming up from a Swift call if it's a warning for bridging to Objective-C conversions of Optionals to Any. But I'm confused...